# laravel with electron is generating white screen

Tags: laravel, electron

i am trying to create a desktop applicaton with laraval and electron  i followd the steps in this link i did not clone the repoitory as it is very old i only used the steps given in the artice
[link](https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-desktop-application-using-electron-js)
and my electon app started when i did `npm start` but it is starting with 500 error

[image]

Comment: i tryed laravel without electron , i insatlled a seprate project just with laravel  still i am getiing 500 error

Comment: i did found out the issue when i did `php artisan serve --port=8080` the app worked the isuue is with 8000 how do i fix that